# Get related products where code are same in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I a products table in one of my laravel projects like below:

```
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->string('code')->nullable();
        $table->integer('brand_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('order')->nullable()->default('1');
        $table->integer('addedby_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('editedby_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I want to get all related products where code are same/equal for a single products. Also I want to load related product count like

```
$products = App\Product::with('relatedProductCount')->get();
```

How I define relation for these? Can Anyone please help;

Comment: And what is the definition of related products?

Comment: where $table->string('code')->nullable() are same or equal

Answer (score 0):

I will probably do it like this:

```
$product = App\Product::find($id);
$related_products = App\Product::where(id,'<>',$product->id)->where('code',$product->code)->get()
$product_count = $related_products->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

For better encapsulation, you can create a `relatedProductCount` method on `Product` model

```
public function relatedProductCount()
{
    return $this->relatedProducts()->count();
}

private function relatedProducts()
{
    return static::where('id', '<>', $this->id)->where('code', $this->code)->get();
}
```

And use it as

```
$product = App\Product::find($id);
$relatedProductCount = $product->relatedProductCount();
```